# Internet Information Service is missing from the list in “Turn Windows features on or off”

Tags: windows-10

I have a Windows 10 Pro x64 install and want to add Internet Information Service feature. But this option is missing from the list in “Turn Windows features on or off”. Why is this happening? Exists way to fix it?

Comment: What environment is your computer in? Home? Corporate?

Comment: It's on my notebook so i'm using it in office and home

Comment: [Try this](http://serverfault.com/questions/112583/iis-not-showing-up-in-windows-component-wizard/112597), it's not specifically for Windows 10, but it may help.

Comment: @MichaelFrank this can't help, because this is for XP and since Vista, Windows uses CBS for setup/feature activation.

Comment: @Max run **sfc /scannow** and **Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth**

Comment: @magicandre1981 i tried your solution but in the end of process i got an error with code 0x800f081f and since restore was too long(~4h) and i didn't have more time i decided to get another system image and reinstall OS. But anyway thank you for your help.

Comment: ok, post this as answer